# How to render java.util.Collection using Playframework template engine?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

I just want to render a simple list. I followed official documentation but IntelliJ is showing an error. This is the code to display a `ul` list:

```
@import java.util 
@(products: util.Collection[String])
 <ul> 
 @for(product <- products) 
 { 
   <li>product</li>  
 } 
 </ul>
```

Could you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code matches exactly what you posted? If so try to put the two statements in the first line in two separated lines (or just remove the import and use java.util.Collection) and use `@product` in the li element. If you get any compilation error add it to your question

Comment: hey thanks,
using this '@import java.util.Collections' giving me 
can not resolve unknown symbol Collection
at '@(products: util.Collection[String])'.


also writing '@import java.util' , 
'@(products: util.Collection[String])' in two lines din't work

Comment: The correct one in `@import java.util.Collection` (without 's') and then `@(products: Collection[String])`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, does it compile in sbt? The IDE may be wrong. Secondly, have you enabled the PlayJava sbt plugin, or the PlayScala? When enabling PlayJava, some extra imports are added to templates to convert Java collections to Scala collections. Finally, have you tried using `java.util.List`? I'm not sure if the imports include something to convert Collection to a Scala Seq.